# Get current active users in the Web application using Elastic/Kibana Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, visualization, elastic-stack, elk

I am new to elastic and kibana. I want to get current active users in web application using audit logs stored in elastic index. We capture login and logout event of user in audit log and stored as document in elastic index.

Below is the sample document:

For logout event:

Jan 23, 2021 @ 17:35:44.893
id: c384f67e-de6a-4161-bcbe-ca434bb62453
entityType:idmauditlogentity
userId:8ac8953561c2db8c0161dbef14c21519
**principal:M31XX**
managedSysId:-
timestamp:Jan 23, 2021 @ 17:35:44.893
source:https://myhostname.com/service/menu/MYINFO
clientIP:100.34.100.25
nodeIP:myhostname
**action:LOGOUT**
**result:SUCCESS**
hash:d5f0d34add6dyedil04e5a38ddmange546bcb630a5470more83bb25db2c317c698a

For login event:
id:07b5ebc6-82ba-4113-a93d-09b6b47278d0
entityType:idmauditlogentity
userId:8ac8953561c2db8c0161dbef14c21519
**principal:M31XXX**
managedSysId:0
timestamp:Jan 23, 2021 @ 17:35:26.465
source:-
clientIP:100.34.100.25
nodeIP:myhostname
**action:LOGIN**
**result:SUCCESS**
hash:facdf7e925670c8f491192ca055c105a47042e122f2b327712c809b0f2d94257

Now here field **principal** is user name, **action** is action performed by user and **result** is either success or failure.

Here logic is that we need to check last **action** (LOGIN/LOGOUT/others) performed by user . If last(latest) performed **action** is not equal to LOGOUT , then consider user as an active user.

Query:

Get the count of users whose name(**principal** field is user name in elastic index) start with either CC*|MM*|VC* and their latest(last) **action** is not equal to LOGOUT.
Help will be greatly appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey geeks ,

Anyone there to guide me !!!

Comment: Hi All, Anyone there to give some tips/hints/guidance on above query